# How to get the revisions feature back on the classic editor?

Tags: block-editor, revisions

Any of the recent Wordpress updates have removed the revision option from the classic editor. It runs in the background and saves the regions but no way to access it on the classic editor. Gutenburg has and supports the revision option well. But I don't use Gutenburg.

I don't know when they removed the feature, but I only realized today. How can I get the feature back on my Classic editor?

I checked my database, I have the revisions, even for new posts, and I also checked by enabling the Block editor.

[image]

Comment: I did some research but found no solution. It seems people are complaining on wordpress.org forum from 2019 about this issue. But no proper solution there.

Comment: WordPress did not disable the feature. But the Revisions section in the Publish metabox and the Revisions metabox are only available if the current post has 1 or more revisions. I've tested on WordPress 5.4.2 with both the Classic Editor plugin and the built-in/core classic editor in WordPress. Or am I not understanding something here?

Comment: I have revisions of posts on my database, but not in the post edit screen. I have tested my posts today.

I have disable the block editor with this: `add_filter('use_block_editor_for_post', '__return_false', 10);` could that be the issue?

Revisions are available if I remove the code and view on the block editor.

Comment: "revisions of posts on my database" - but for the current post you're editing, does it actually have any revisions? And that filter hook should be good, but have you tried using the Classic Editor [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/classic-editor/)?

Comment: Also, try switching to a default theme and if necessary, try deactivating plugins to see if a plugin is causing the issue.

Comment: Thanks @SallyCJ : Classic editor plugin works. Currently, I'm looking into the plugin codes. I will try to use the editor as the plugin do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used to disable the Gutenberg with this:

```
//disable gutenburg
add_filter('use_block_editor_for_post', '__return_false', 10);
```

This filter disables the Gutenberg sitewide but it doesn't work smoothly in other custom-post-types. Not only the revisions but other features are also hidden on the post edit screen of custom-post-types.

Changing this to the post type filter works smoothly across all post types.

```
//disable Gutenburg
add_filter( 'use_block_editor_for_post_type', '__return_false', 10 );
```